# How to get QML object's id property using C++ API

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I need to parse a QML tree and get `id`s of all QML objects along the way which have it. I noticed that `id`s don't behave like normal properties (see the example below) – value returned from `obj->property` call is an invalid `QVariant`.

My question is – is there a way to retrieve object's `id`, even in some hacky (but reproductible) way?

Simplified example:

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    Item {
        id: howToGetThis
        objectName: "item"
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    QTimer::singleShot(1000, [&]() {
        auto item = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QObject*>("item");
        qDebug() << item->property("objectName");
        qDebug() << item->property("id");
    });

    return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
QVariant(QString, "item")
QVariant(Invalid)
```

Comment: If I could've used `objectName`, I've used it. Solution from the accepted answer does what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
QString QQmlContext::nameForObject(QObject *object)
```

You can find the description here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#nameForObject

> Returns the name of object in this context, or an empty string if object is not named in the context. Objects are named by setContextProperty(), or ***by ids in the case of QML created contexts***.

---

Based on comments received, a common pitfall is to call `nameForObject` using the wrong `QQmlContext`. (When that happens, you just the empty string.) To help with that, here is a more complete example:

```
  QQuickItem* const focus_item = my_QQuickWindow->activeFocusItem();
  if (!focus_item) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no item has focus");
  } else {
    // There are many contexts in a hierarchy. You have to get the right one:
    QQmlContext* const context = qmlContext(focus_item);
    if (!context) {
      // Unsure if this branch of code is even reachable:
      fprintf(stderr, "item is not in any context?");
    } else {
      const QString focus_item_id = context->nameForObject(focus_item);
      fprintf(stderr, "focus item: %s\n", focus_item_id.toStdString().c_str());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the following prints an empty string: `qDebug() << engine.rootContext()->nameForObject(item);`

Comment: @Luke what about `qmlContext(item)->nameForObject(item)`?

Comment: @GrecKo What do you mean exactly – what's `qmlContext`?

Comment: A non member function : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlContext

Comment: @GrecKo Thank you very much! This works as expected: `qmlContext(item)->nameForObject(item);`